# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token - next js (build error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, strapi

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[2]!./styles/index.css
/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/jit/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:1

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
event - build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
wait  - compiling...
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[2]!./styles/index.css
/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/jit/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:1

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
Error: Cannot find module '/home/centos/straive/frontend/.next/build-manifest.json'
Require stack:
- /home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js
- /home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js
- /home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js
- /home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
- /home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
- /home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js
- /home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:4:1855)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at loadComponents (/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js:1:1557)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponents (/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:77:257)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToHTML (/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:139:266)
    at async DevServer.render (/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:75:160) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js',
    '/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js',
    '/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js',
    '/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js',
    '/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js',
    '/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js',
    '/home/centos/straive/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
  ]
}
```

I am getting this error when building my next js project. I have checked my index.css file and there are no syntax errors.

The next js version I am using is next: 10.0.0

I am getting this error only on staging environment whereas on live and local it works fine.

Here is the package json file.

```
{
  "name": "cms-strapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "develop": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.2.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.1",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001246",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "date-fns": "2.14.0",
    "embla-carousel": "^4.5.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "gsap": "^3.7.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next": "^10.0.0",
    "next-seo": "^4.7.1",
    "next-share": "^0.6.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.10.377",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.2.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-compare-slider": "^2.1.0",
    "react-countup": "^4.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.32.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.3.1",
    "react-particles-js": "^3.5.3",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-tsparticles": "^1.37.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "tsparticles": "^1.36.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "next-sitemap": "^1.6.179",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.2.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.4"
  }
}
```

I have tried to delete the frontend directory and copy the one from my local (since it's working on local) but I am getting the same issue.